# ionic 4/5 using ngx-translate auto add to subtitle files in i18n

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

Is there a way to auto add translation words to i18n folders?
Is there a way to automatically add subtitle words to i18n folders?

Using below url
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/ng2-translate/

When I add below lines as an example:

```html
<ion-title>{{ 'HELLO' | translate }}</ion-title>
<p>{{ 'HI' | translate }}</p>
```

I expect to find under files
./assets/i18n/en.json
./assets/i18n/es.json

```json
{
  ...
  "HELLO": "HELLO",
  "HI": "HI"
}
```

After that, it is easier to update json files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, [ngx-translate-extract](https://github.com/biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract) does exaclty what you need.

```json
{
    "scripts": {
      "i18n:init": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/template.json --key-as-default-value --replace --format json",
      "i18n:extract": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/{en,da,de,fi,nb,nl,sv}.json --clean --format json"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you save my time.
I have tried it very simple and useful.